# ListBox ItemSource binding asks for Dependency property from unknown reason

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Hi I have the following UserControl. 
Can notice that in the second **HierarchicalDataTemplate** contains also a ListBox.

I would like the ListBox ItemsSource to bind to the a field in the viewModel taht is *CurrentPropertyValues* .

When I try to bind it in the mainwindow or just outside the tree, it works, (just ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPropertyValues}")

I tried various things to make it work inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate (it has a different data context) but I keep on failing.

Thanks for any help!

```
<UserControl x:Class="RidaDiff2.Views.LeftTreeControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:RidaDiff2.Converters"
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:RidaDiff2.Model"
         xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:RidaDiff2.ViewModels"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:RidaDiff2.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:EnumToPicConverter x:Key="Converter" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildListNodes}" x:Key="NotSelected">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=EntityType,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Name1}" />
            <!--"{Binding ItemName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" -->
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildListNodes}" x:Key="Selected">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=EntityType,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Name1}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <ListBox DataContext="viewModel:TreeViewModel" Height="300" Width="100"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(viewModel:TreeViewModel.CurrentPropertyValues), Mode=TwoWay}" ></ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<views:ExtendedTreeView x:Name="Tree"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding RootNode}" SelectedItem_="{Binding CurrentCouple,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <views:ExtendedTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=(model:TreeNode.IsExpanded), Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(model:TreeNode.BackgroundColor), Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=(model:TreeNode.IsSelected), Mode=TwoWay}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource NotSelected}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Selected}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </views:ExtendedTreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</views:ExtendedTreeView>
```

Comment: `CurrentPropertyValues` is part of which view model? The one attached to `UserControl`?

Comment: `DataContext="viewModel:TreeViewModel"` is just assigning a string to ListBox's DataContext. It is the same as doing `DataContext="Hello World"`. I guess the viewmodel is the DataContext of the TreeView (or UserControl); in this case you need to do binding from your itemtemplate which seeks out the appropriate ancestor container (with regard to visual/logical tree) and access the viewmodel through its DataContext property. The binding should do something like `"{Binding DataContext.MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:ExtendedTreeView}}}}"`

Comment: @dkozl - `CurrentPropertyValues` is part of `TreeViewModel`, and yes, this is the one attached to the `UserControl`.

@elgonzo - It doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `CurrentPropertyValues` is a property of `TreeViewModel` then you can use `RelativeSource` binding and go up the visual tree to find `TreeView` and bind `ItemsSource` to property of its `DataContext`:

```
<ListBox 
    Height="300" 
    Width="100"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}, Path=DataContext.CurrentPropertyValues}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it work, I appreciate your answer!
I would +1 but i don't have enough reputation..